# How to Insert dates if some of the dates are missing in the original array of objects

Tags: javascript

Below is my data, which is an array of objects.

```
const myArray = [
{name: "Dave", date: "2020-07-30T17:30:46.180Z", score: 50, age: 20},
{name: "Dave", date: "2020-06-30T17:30:26.160Z", score: 35, age: 20},
{name: "Cosmo", date: "2020-06-30T17:30:26.160Z", score: 65, age: 22},
{name: "Dave", date: "2020-05-30T15:30:16.160Z", score: 65, age: 20},
{name: "Carlos", date: "2020-07-30T17:30:46.180Z", score: 70, age: 28},
{name: "Carlos", date: "2020-06-30T17:30:26.160Z", score: 53, age: 28},
];
```

The expected result is to make sure each individual has a score for each date. The score should be `null` when the date is missing for the individual.

Expected result

```
[
{name: "Dave", date: "2020-07-30T17:30:46.180Z", score: 50, age: 20},
{name: "Dave", date: "2020-06-30T17:30:26.160Z", score: 35, age: 20},
{name: "Dave", date: "2020-05-30T15:30:16.160Z", score: 65, age: 20},
{name: "Cosmo", date: "2020-06-30T17:30:26.160Z", score: 65, age: 22},
{name: "Cosmo", date: "2020-07-30T17:30:46.180Z", score: null, age: 22},
{name: "Cosmo", date: "2020-05-30T15:30:16.160Z", score: null, age: 22},
{name: "Carlos", date: "2020-07-30T17:30:46.180Z", score: 70, age: 28},
{name: "Carlos", date: "2020-06-30T17:30:26.160Z", score: 53, age: 28},
{name: "Carlos", date: "2020-05-30T15:30:16.160Z", score: null, age: 28}
];
```

My attempt to solve this problem can be found below. It didn't really work. What changes should I make?

```js
const myArray = [
{name: "Dave", date: "2020-07-30T17:30:46.180Z", score: 50, age: 20},
{name: "Dave", date: "2020-06-30T17:30:26.160Z", score: 35, age: 20},
{name: "Cosmo", date: "2020-06-30T17:30:26.160Z", score: 65, age: 22},
{name: "Dave", date: "2020-05-30T15:30:16.160Z", score: 65, age: 20},
{name: "Carlos", date: "2020-07-30T17:30:46.180Z", score: 70, age: 28},
{name: "Carlos", date: "2020-06-30T17:30:26.160Z", score: 53, age: 28},
];
  
// Get unique dates
const getUniqueDates = (data) => {
    let temp = [];
    data.forEach(el => {

        if (temp.indexOf(el.date) === -1) {
            temp.push(el.date);
        }
    })
    return temp;
}

const myDates = getUniqueDates(myArray);

// Use a nested loop to verify whether date exists or not and insert objects
const getCleanData = () => {
    let temp = [];
    myDates.forEach(el => {

        for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            let obj = {};
            obj['name'] = myArray[i].name;
            obj['age'] = myArray[i].age;
            if (el === myArray[i].date && typeof myArray[i].date !== 'undefined') {
                obj['score'] = myArray[i].score;
                obj['date'] = myArray[i].date;
                temp.push(obj);
            } else {
                obj['score'] = null;
                obj['date'] = el;
            }
        }

    })
    return temp;
}

console.log(getCleanData());
```

Comment: Is the order of the output records important? Or could they be sorted by name then date or by date then name?

Comment: No, the order of the output is not important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach.  We calculate the list of unique dates, group the records by name, and then flatMap that result into arrays of elements formed by `map`ping the dates and choosing the existing match or creating a new one from a simple template based on the first record for that person:

```js
const addMissingDates = (records) => {
  const dates = [... new Set(records .map (r => r.date))]
  const byName = Object .values (records .reduce (
    (a, x) => ({...a, [x.name]: [...(a[x.name] || []), x]}), 
    {}
  ))
  return byName .flatMap (person => {
    const {score, date, ...rest} = person[0] 
    return dates .map (
      d => person .find (({date}) => d == date) || {...rest, date: d, score: null}
    )
  })
}

const myArray = [{name: "Dave", date: "2020-07-30T17:30:46.180Z", score: 50, age: 20}, {name: "Dave", date: "2020-06-30T17:30:26.160Z", score: 35, age: 20}, {name: "Cosmo", date: "2020-06-30T17:30:26.160Z", score: 65, age: 22}, {name: "Dave", date: "2020-05-30T15:30:16.160Z", score: 65, age: 20}, {name: "Carlos", date: "2020-07-30T17:30:46.180Z", score: 70, age: 28}, {name: "Carlos", date: "2020-06-30T17:30:26.160Z", score: 53, age: 28},]

console .log (addMissingDates (myArray))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

**Update**: fixed a bug and added a simplification inspired by uke's answer.

**Update 2**: Another implementation of the same idea, using my preferred expressions-rather-than-statements style:

```js
const addMissingDates = (records, dates = [... new Set(records .map (r => r.date))]) => 
  Object .values (records .reduce (
    (a, x) => ({...a, [x.name]: [...(a[x.name] || []), x]}), 
    {}
  )) .flatMap ((person, _, __, {score, date, ...rest} = person [0]) => dates .map (
    d => person .find (({date}) => d == date) || {...rest, date: d, score: null}
  ))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a cartesian product of names and dates and store the names for getting a tamplate.

```js
const
    data = [{ name: "Dave", date: "2020-07-30T17:30:46.180Z", score: 50, age: 20 }, { name: "Dave", date: "2020-06-30T17:30:26.160Z", score: 35, age: 20 }, { name: "Cosmo", date: "2020-06-30T17:30:26.160Z", score: 65, age: 22 }, { name: "Dave", date: "2020-05-30T15:30:16.160Z", score: 65, age: 20 }, { name: "Carlos", date: "2020-07-30T17:30:46.180Z", score: 70, age: 28 }, { name: "Carlos", date: "2020-06-30T17:30:26.160Z", score: 53, age: 28 }],
    temp = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        r.date[o.date] = true;
        r.name[o.name] = o;
        (r[o.name] ??= {})[o.date] = o;
        return r;
    }, { date: {}, name: {} }),
    result = Object
        .entries(temp.name)
        .flatMap(([name, o]) => Object
            .keys(temp.date)
            .map(date => temp[name]?.[date] || { ...o, date, score: null })
        );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The dates are not correct in your answer.

Comment: @DamienAsseya, right, sorry. please see edit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know all possible dates first and the group by name, this will sort your data by name.

```js
const allDates = Array.from(new Set(myArray.map(it=>it.date)))
```

Then use it in combination with groupBy

```js
Object.entries(groupBy(myArray, (it) => it.name))
    .map(([name,personDates]) =>
        allDates.map(
            (date) =>
                personDates.find((it) => it.date === date) || {
                    name,
                    date,
                    score: null,
                    age: null,
                }
        )
    )
    .flat();
```

You can use [_.groupBY](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy) or use this answer to recreate it [Most efficient method to groupby on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects)

Finally you need to use [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to remove the array of arrays

Comment: Please check out [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992).  Also note that the extra records you generate here don't have the `name` field.

Answer (score -1):

To check if a property is in an object, use the `in` operator. For example:

```js
if (!("date" in el)) {
    // executes if there is no date property.
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant to the question.  If it is, it should be a comment, as this is far from an actual answer to the question.